# How to set auto increment value to the primary key in ActiveAndroid

Tags: activeandroid

I'm new to active Android and I have done CRUD operation, but I am unable to set auto increment for the primary key. I already tried below code but it is of not use to me:

```
@Table(name = "Employee", id = "EmpId")

public class Employee extends Model {
    @Column(name = "empid")
    public long empid;
    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;
}
```

Here `employee` is my tablename. I have primary 2 fields, one is `empid` and `name`. I need to set auto increment value to the primary key.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To do an update with a unique column as your pseudo primary key, the annotation would look something like this:

```
  @Column(name = "empid", unique = true, onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
        public long empid;
```

As we can read in a [documentation](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Creating-your-database-model):

> One important thing to note is that ActiveAndroid creates an **id field**
>   for your tables. This field is an **auto-incrementing primary key**.

Moreover, if you would like to create custom primary key in you model, you can check solution mentioned in [GitHub issue connected with ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/22#issuecomment-81670905), which looks like this:

```
 @Table(name = "Employee", id = "EmpId")

public class Employee extends Model {
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;
}
```

Then, id field is custom primary key, which will be auto-incremented.